# Help connecting to wifi on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, system-installation, networksetup

I'm trying to install Arch Linux on a dual boot (overwriting a root partition that previously had Fedora). I connected to WiFi easily enough on the installation USB but can't manage to on the real installation.

Some things worth mentioning:

- On the USB the interface was called `wlp2s0b1`. This doesn't seem to exist on the installation
- I installed `dialog`, `wpa_supplicant`, `wpa_actiond` and `iw` through chroot from the USB (on the installation)
- `ip link` doesn't show anything that starts with a `w`, only `lo` and `enp1s0`. On the USB it had a third thing, `wlp2s0b1`
- `iw dev` returns `nl80211 not found`.
- wifi worked fine on Fedora
- I have run `systemctl enable netctl-auto@wlp2s0b1.service`. When run without `sudo` it returns `Failed to enable unit: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files`. When run with `sudo` there's no output, but wifi still doesn't work.
- `ip link set wlp2s0b1 up` returns `Cannot find device "wlp2s0b1"`
- @GAD3R asked for the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` so here it is:

  `lspci: Unable to load libkmod resources: error -12
  02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:051b]`

I'm completely lost and would appreciate help getting my wifi working.

Comment: Please edit by adding the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Answer (score 1):

To get the wifi working you need to install the [`broadcom-wl-dkms`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/broadcom-wl-dkms/) package:

[Description :](https://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11)

> **Linux® STA 64-bit driver**
>
> These packages contain Broadcom's IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n hybrid Linux®® device driver for use with Broadcom's BCM4311-, BCM4312-, **BCM4313**-, BCM4321-, BCM4322-, BCM43224-, and BCM43225-, BCM43227- and BCM43228-based hardware. There are different tars for 32-bit and 64-bit x86 CPU architectures. Make sure that you download the appropriate tar because the hybrid binary file must be of the appropriate architecture type. The hybrid binary file is agnostic to the specific version of the Linux® kernel because it is designed to perform all interactions with the operating system through operating-system-specific files and an operating system abstraction layer file. All Linux® operating-system-specific code is provided in source form, making it possible to retarget to different kernel versions and fix operating system related issues. NOTE: You must read the LICENSE.TXT file in the lib directory before using this software. Support questions for the latest version of these drivers may be directed to linux®-wlan-client-support-list@broadcom.com.
>
> BCM4311 ,  BCM4312 ,   BCM4322 ,   **BCM4313** ,   BCM43224

```
pacman -S broadcom-wl-dkms
```

Unload conflicting modules:

```
modprobe -r b43 ssb bcma
```

Reload the `wl` module:

```
modprobe -r wl
modprobe wl
```

[Broadcom wireless on Archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless)

Comment: @TheInitializer did it work?

Comment: @cw tested and work fine under `bcm43142` , waiting @TheInitializer to confirm it.

Comment: @cw welp I tried doing some things myself and ended up completely screwing my entire system up. This question is kinda "on hold" until I fix that. In the meantime you can help me with my new problem at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316846/194205

Comment: It seems like an intelligent answer though so I'll upvote it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just deleting the entire partition and reinstalling. Works perfectly now

Answer (score -1):

Many firmware images are provided by the `linux-firmware` package which is installed by default, but you maybe need to install your cards driver manually.

[From the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Check_the_driver_status): To check if the driver for your card has been loaded, check the output of the `lspci -k` or `lsusb -v` command, depending on if the card is connected by PCI(e) or USB. Then check kernel messages for firmware being loaded with `dmesg | grep firmware`. If the kernel module is not loaded go on to section [Installing Driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Installing_driver.2Ffirmware).

Comment: The `lspci -k` command shows my network controller, but only two lines: `Network controller` and `Subsystem`. I remember there being two more lines on the USB

Comment: would be great to see a screenshot of your terminal

Comment: I don't have a DE and don't think you can take a screenshot in TTY - plus I don't have wifi to upload it with

Comment: How are you posting here then? Mobile Device?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a phone.

Comment: Then please take a photo.

Comment: @C.W. the broadcom driver isn't included in the `linux-firmware`

Comment: @GAD3R yes i see, unfortunately i posted my recommendation befor the rusults of `lspci` were given.